# SwfitUI Decode Holidays JSON

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to download, decode and then display a list of UK Holidays from a JSON file.

I've written the below with some help from a couple of YouTube videos, but when it comes to pulling the data into a list I'm getting a bit stuck - ideally I want to end up with a list just from the EnglandAndWales struct with the Event Name and Date.

I'm getting an error that the data isn't identifiable, but not sure how I can fix that?

Any tips would be appreciated!

Thank you,

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation


struct Book: Codable {
    let englandAndWales, scotland, northernIreland: EnglandAndWales

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case englandAndWales = "england-and-wales"
        case scotland
        case northernIreland = "northern-ireland"
    }
}


struct EnglandAndWales: Codable {
    let division: String
    let events: [Event]
}


struct Event: Codable {
    let title, date: String
    let notes: Notes
    let bunting: Bool
}



enum Notes: String, Codable {
    case empty = ""
    case substituteDay = "Substitute day"
}



class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var base: [Book] = []
    
    func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL(string:
                                "https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json") else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {[weak self] data,_,
            error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            //Converts to JSON
            
            do {
                let base = try JSONDecoder().decode([Book].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.base = base
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List {
                ForEach(Book.englandAndWales.events) { item in
                    Text(item.self)
                }
        }
            .navigationTitle("Holidays")
            .onAppear{
                viewModel.fetch()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. The root object is a dictionary, you have to decode

   ```
   let base = try JSONDecoder().decode(Book.self, from: data)
   ```
2. As you are obviously only interested in the events declare in `ViewModel`

   ```
   @Published var events: [Event] = []
   ```

   and assign

   ```
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self?.events = base.englandAndWales.events
   }
   ```
3. In the view `Book.englandAndWales.events` cannot work at all, you have to get the data from `viewModel`.
4. And `Text(item.self)` cannot work either because `item` is an `Event` instance, you have to get the values of its properties. The *identifiable* error can be fixed by adding the `id` parameter. The dates are unique, so they are perfect for the identification

   ```
   ForEach(viewModel.events, id: \.date) { event in
      HStack {
         Text(event.title)
         Spacer()
         Text(event.date)
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you! I'm with you except for Point 3, how do I get the data from the viewModel?

Comment: The code in point 4 includes point 3

Comment: Ah, so on the line "self?.events = base.englandAndWales.events" I'm getting a "Value of type '[Book]' has no member 'englandAndWales" error?

Comment: Please read point 1 closely.

Comment: Ahhh yes, got it! :) thank you, this works.